# Laravel How To Sub Join with Relations

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pull NPCs with pledges by day. However, with this i need the dungeon name. İ have 3 tables.

Npcs Table:

```
id  |  name
-----------
1   | NPC 1
2   | NPC 2
3   | NPC 3
```

Dungeons table

```
id  |  name
---------------
1   | Dungeon 1
2   | Dungeon 2
3   | Dungeon 3
4   | Dungeon 4
5   | Dungeon 5
6   | Dungeon 6
```

Pledges table

```
id  |  npc_id  |  dungeon_id  |  date
------------------------------------------
1   | 1        | 1            | 2019-05-26
2   | 2        | 2            | 2019-05-26
3   | 3        | 3            | 2019-05-26
4   | 1        | 4            | 2019-05-27
5   | 2        | 5            | 2019-05-27
6   | 3        | 6            | 2019-05-27
```

My controller code;

```
public function index()
{
    $y = Carbon::yesterday('Europe/London');
    $t = Carbon::today('Europe/London');
    $time = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
    $yesterday = Carbon::create($y->year, $y->month, $y->day, 10, 0, 0); //set time to 10:00
    $today = Carbon::create($t->year, $t->month, $t->day, 10, 0, 0); //set time to 10:00
    if($time->between($yesterday, $today, true)) {
        $pledges = Npc::join('pledges', function ($join) {
            $join->on('npcs.id', '=', 'pledges.npc_id')
                ->where('pledges.date', '=', Carbon::yesterday('Europe/London'));
        })
            ->get();
        return $pledges;
    } else {
        $pledges = Npc::join('pledges', function ($join) {
            $join->on('npcs.id', '=', 'pledges.npc_id')
                ->where('pledges.date', '=', Carbon::today('Europe/London'));
        })
            ->get();
        return $pledges;
    }
}
```

This code gives me the following result.

```
0
id  5
name    "NPC 1"
created_at  "2019-05-27 11:35:27"
updated_at  "2019-05-27 11:35:27"
npc_id  1
dungeon_id  1
date    "2019-05-27"
```

But i need dungeon name with this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use additional join + select. Try this.

```
public function index()
{
    $time = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
    $yesterday = Carbon::yesterday('Europe/London')->setTime(10, 0, 0);
    $today = Carbon::today('Europe/London')->setTime(10, 0, 0);

    if($time->between($yesterday, $today, true)){
        $date = $yesterday;
    } else {
        $date = $today;
    }

    $pledges = Npc::select('npcs.*', 'dungeons.id as dungeon_id', 'dungeons.name as dungeon_name')
        ->join('pledges', function($join) use ($date) {
            $join->on('npcs.id', '=', 'pledges.npc_id')->where('date', $date);
        })
        ->join('dungeons', 'dungeons.id', '=', 'pledges.dungeon_id')
        ->get();

    return $pledges;
}
```

Comment: i get this error,
```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dungeon" LINE 1: select "npcs".*, "dungeon"."id" as "dungeon_id", "dungeon"."... ^ (SQL: select "npcs".*, "dungeon"."id" as "dungeon_id", "dungeon"."name" as "dungeon_name" from "npcs" inner join "pledges" on "npcs"."id" = "pledges"."npc_id" and "date" = 2019-05-27 10:00:00 inner join "dungeons" on "dungeons"."id" = "pledges"."dungeon_id")
```